# Adding Text to the End of My Bars - D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization

I am currently making a Bar Graph which shows data in the form of a horizontal bar which grows based on the data put into the code. What I am trying to do here is make text appear next to the bars when they appear and change as the data does. I have already made a listener which changes the data appearing I just do not know how to make the data appear and change.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta>
  <meta name="description" content="Drawing Shapes w/ D3 - " />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Resources per Project</title>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    h1 {
      font-size: 35px;
      color: darkgrey;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      border-bottom-width: 3px;
      border-bottom-style: dashed;
      border-bottom-color: black;
    }
    
    h2 {
      font-size: 20px;
      color: black;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      text-decoration: underline;
      margin-left: 350px;
      margin-top: 0px; 
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Resources used per Project</h1>

  <p>Choose Month:
    <select id="label-option">
      <option value="April">April</option>
      <option value="May">May</option>
      <option value="June">June</option>
      <option value="July">July</option>
      <option value="August">August</option>
      <option value="September">September</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var width = 800
      var height = 500
      var emptyVar = 0
      var dataArrayProjects = ['2G', 'An', 'At', 'Au', 'AW', 'Ch', 'CI', 'CN']
      var April = [0.35, 1.66, 3.04, 1.54, 3.45, 2.56, 2.29, 1.37]
      var May = [0.36, 1.69, 3.08, 1.54, 3.62, 2.61, 2.22, 1.44]
      var June = [0.34, 1.7, 3.08, 1.63, 3.66, 2.68, 2.24, 1.51]
      var July = [0.3, 1.72, 3.17, 1.67, 3.56, 2.56, 2.17, 1.44]
      var August = [0.28, 1.79, 3.18, 1.71, 3.62, 2.73, 2.26, 1.54]
      var September = [1.23, 1.74, 3.12, 1.61, 3.66, 2.71, 2.2, 1.48]

      d3.select("#label-option").on("change", change)

      function change() {
        var data = April;
        if (this.selectedIndex == 1){
          data = May;
        } else if (this.selectedIndex == 2){
          data = June;
        } else if (this.selectedIndex == 3){
          data = July;
        } else if (this.selectedIndex == 4){
          data = August;
        } else if (this.selectedIndex == 5){
          data = September;
        }
        canvas.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .attr("width", emptyVar)
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return color(d)
        })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return i * 55
        })

       bars.transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .delay(200)
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return widthScale(d);
        })        
      }

      var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 4])
        .range([0, width - 60]);

      var heightScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(dataArrayProjects)
        .rangePoints([10, height - 85]);

      var color = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 4])
        .range(["#000033", "#22cdff"])

      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .ticks("30")
        .scale(widthScale);

      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(heightScale)
        .orient("left");

      var canvas = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(40, 0)");

      var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
        .data(April)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", emptyVar)
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return color(d)
        })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return i * 55
        })
       
      canvas.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, 430)")
        .attr("font-family", "Helvetica")
        .attr("font-size", "15px")
        .call(xAxis);

      canvas.append("g")
        .attr("font-family", "Helvetica")
        .attr("font-size", "15px")
        .style("fill", "black")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

      bars.transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .delay(200)
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return widthScale(d);
        })

      var yAxisLine = canvas.append("line")
                        .attr("x1", -3)
                        .attr("y1", 0)
                        .attr("x2", -3)
                        .attr("y2", 436)
                        .attr("stroke-width", 6)
                        .attr("stroke", "black");

      canvas.selectAll("text")
         .data(April)
         .enter()
           .append("text")
              .text(function(d) {
          return April;
     })
         .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (width / April.length);
     })
         .attr("y", function(d) {
        return height - (April * 4);
     });


    </script>
    <h2>Resources</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the data is not easily readable and hard to understand without knowing the precise number within the data. How do I make numbers appear next to the bars which say the exact amount of data being displayed. Please do not link other bar graphs with their own tooltips as I am not very good with d3.js and do not understand other graphs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by first creating labels like below:

```
var texts = canvas.selectAll(".label")//select all DOMs with class label.
        .data(April)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return widthScale(d) + 10;//x location of the label
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return color(d)
        })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return (i * 55) + 25; //y location of the label
        })
        .text(function(d, i) {
          return d;
        })
```

Finally in the update section do the following to update the labels.

```
    texts = canvas.selectAll(".label")
    .data(data)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return widthScale(d) + 10;
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d)
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return (i * 55) + 25
    })
    .text(function(d, i) {
      return d;
    })
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MI5jPhSVDCYpk15gMdru?p=preview)